# Cannot connect to localhost?

Tags: localhost

I am trying to connect to my localhost for some application development.  But I keep getting an error saying could not connect to localhost.  I do not have Apache, or mySQL, or anything like that installed, and I don't need it. I am using windows vista and I have Norton Security Suite installed.  Could someone please help me?  Also, I tried to telnet to the localhost and I got nothing.

Comment: What are you trying to connect to then? If you don't have a web server, database, telnet server, ... installed, what is it you're trying to access?

Comment: Windows doesn't enable the Telnet service by default, see [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732046(v=ws.10).aspx) for information on how to enable the telnet service on Windows.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have Apache installed? How do you expect to connect to a server that doesn't exist? localhost is the domain name (IP 127.0.0.1) for a server that runs locally on your computer. If the server isn't there, it can't be connected to.

Comment: @Mat realized my mistake and edited. sorry :P

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a server. `Download and install apache`: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/windows.html#down

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have any server installed probably you are devoloping some server-client application that listen on a particular port.
If you are sure that 'something' is listening on a particular port try to disable your Norton Security Suite and connect.

UPDATE 
If you can connect then its the firewall, restart  norton add an excption for your application.

Comment: yes I am trying to access a google api, and I disabled my firewall and it still doesn't work